# build error jenkins pipeline with propogate false

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
def TESTBED_NAME_VAR              = params.testbed_name
def RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR    = params.radium_image_file_path
def FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR    = params.fugazi_image_file_path
def NEPTUNE_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR    = params.neptune_image_file_path
def THALLIUM_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.thallium_platform
def THORIUM_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.thorium_platform
def RADIUM_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.radium_platform
def URANIUM_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.uranium_platform
def FUGAZI_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.fugazi_platform
def NEPTUNE_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.neptune_platform
def PROMETHIUM_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.promethium_platform
def UUT_SN_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.uut_sn_platform
def HUB_SN_PLATFORM_VAR    = params.hub_sn_platform
def MAIL_TO_VAR          = params.mail_to
def BRANCH_NAME_VAR      = "master"
 

currentBuild.description=TESTBED_NAME_VAR

//Mail to is mandatory
if(MAIL_TO_VAR=="") 
{ 
  currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
  error("mail_to is empty")
} 


pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("copy_images") {
            parallel {
                stage("copy_radium_image") {
                    when { expression {RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/FILE_COPY", parameters: [
                            string(name: "source_file_path", value: RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR),
                            string(name: "testbed", value: TESTBED_NAME_VAR)
                            ]
                    }

                }
                stage("copy_fugazi_image") {
                    when { expression {FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/FILE_COPY", parameters: [
                            string(name: "source_file_path", value: FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR),
                            string(name: "testbed", value: TESTBED_NAME_VAR)
                            ]
                    }
                }
                stage("copy_neptune_image") {
                    when { expression {NEPTUNE_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/FILE_COPY", parameters: [
                            string(name: "source_file_path", value: NEPTUNE_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR),
                            string(name: "testbed", value: TESTBED_NAME_VAR)
                            ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("install_images") {
            parallel {
                    stage ("install_thallium_new_image") {
                    when { expression {THALLIUM_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split('/').last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Thallium_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "THALLIUM ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }   
                stage ("install_thorium_new_image") {
                    when { expression {THORIUM_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split('/').last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Thorium_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "THORIUM ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_radium_new_image") {
                    when { expression {RADIUM_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Radium_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "RADIUM ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_uranium_new_image") {
                    when { expression {URANIUM_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Uranium_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "URANIUM ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_promethium_new_image") {
                    when { expression {PROMETHIUM_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = RADIUM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Promethium_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "PROMETHIUM ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_fugazi_new_image") {
                    when { expression {FUGAZI_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Fugazi_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "FUGAZI ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ]
                                , propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_neptune_new_image") {
                    when { expression {NEPTUNE_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = NEPTUNE_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Neptune_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "NEPTUNE ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }  
                stage ("install_uut_sn_new_image") {
                    when { expression {UUT_SN_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/UUT_SN_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "UUT_SN ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                }
                stage ("install_hub_sn_new_image") {
                    when { expression {HUB_SN_PLATFORM_VAR} }
                    steps {
                            script { 
                                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/HUB_SN_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                                string(name: "platform_name", value: "HUB_SN ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                                ], propagate:false
                            }            
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: WorkflowScript: 164: unexpected token: , @ line 164,
> column 33.
> , propagate:false

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a newline at line 163 before `propagate:false`. Try removing it.

```
stage ("install_fugazi_new_image") {
    when { expression {FUGAZI_PLATFORM_VAR} }
    steps {
            script { 
                def IMAGE_FILE_VAR = FUGAZI_IMAGE_FILE_PATH_VAR.split("/").last()
                def TESTBED_FILE = "./curie/testbed_files/Fugazi_${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}.yaml"
                def INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS = "./job_files/image_upload_job.py --testbed-file  ${TESTBED_FILE} --image_file ${IMAGE_FILE_VAR} --mail-to ${MAIL_TO_VAR}"
                echo "args for install_new_image= ${INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS}"

                build job: "/team_eng_ent_routing/CURIE/Helper_Projects/PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR", parameters: [
                string(name: "pyats_job_args", value: INSTALL_IMAGE_ARGS),
                string(name: "branch_name", value: BRANCH_NAME_VAR),
                string(name: "platform_name", value: "FUGAZI ${TESTBED_NAME_VAR}")
                ], propagate:false
            }            
    }
}
```